# "Earliest" vs "earliest one"

Tags: phrases

Are both the following sentences correct?

> 1. These books were the earliest ones to feature such thing.
> 2. These books were the earliest to feature such thing.

Comment: 'Ones' is superfluous but is correct. 'Such thing' isn't correct; you can choose between 'such a thing' or 'such things'.

Comment: @JMB The word may not be superfluous, it just isn't phrased the best way if it is required. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

By including "ones" you are referring back to the thing previously mentioned - "books". So you are in fact saying:

> These were the earliest **books** to feature such a thing.

This is more specific - but leaves the possibility open that *other things* besides books featured the 'thing'.

Consider these examples:

1. The woman Valentina Tereshkova was the first in space.
2. Valentina Tereshkova was the first woman in space.

Even though *example 1* states she was a woman, it suggests that Tereshkova was the first *person* in space, which is not correct - that was a man, Yuri Gagarin. *Example 2* makes it clear that she was the first woman, leaving it open that others might have gone before her that were not women.

So, if you want to say that the books were the earliest *media* to 'feature' something, your example 2 is fine. If you want to be quite specific and say that they were just the first among books, then use your example 1 (or my alternative version).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precise answer. You obviously know better than me as a native (!), but wouldn't you agree that what is certainly true in your example (where "the first" can be understood as "the first person") is less likely to apply to books? Would "these books were the earliest to feature something" really be untrue if, say, an earlier painting featured the same thing / idea? I absolutely hear you in your example with "first" and "people," but can't feel sure it would also apply to things. Thanks.